# Exchange 2013 Public Folder Search and partial matches with latest CU

Tags: exchange-2013, search, public-folders

We recently updated our clients Exchange 2013 Server to the latest CU and noticed annoying changes in the search behavior.
Whereas in the past the client would be able to search for partial matches of order numbers that appear in mail messages stored in Public Folders, this does not work consistently anymore.

- Sometimes no results are found when entering the number. E.g. searching for "202068674" doesn't work, but searching for "LS202068674" does.
- Sometimes partial matches work as expected. We could not find any regularity.
- If we only search in the subject, it seems to consistently find all matches, also partial ones. E.g. searching for "17122" has no matches, but searching for subject:17122 has 4 matches. But of course only searching in the subject is not enough.

The search index on the server is healthy btw. So my question is if anyone else has noticed this and if there is a way to switch back to the old behavior.

Comment: Hi, it's been a long time. Is there any update? If your problem has been fixed, you could mark the best answer or share your resolutions. Have a nice day:-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you encounter the same issues on the OWA?

See if the services **Microsoft Exchange Search** and **Microsoft Exchange Search Host Controller** are running on your Exchange 2013 server

Try to run the following commands to see if the search index is running well on your server(**ContentIndexState**):

```
Get-PublicFolder | fl MailboxOwnerId
Get-Mailbox -PublicFolder -Identity <Public Folder Mailbox Name> | fl Database
Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Identity "<PF Mailbox Database Name>" | fl *Index*
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. The ContentIndexState is Healthy. To be able to search Public Folders in OWA, we would need to add them to the Favorites first. But the customer has hundreds of subfolders, so that would not be a viable approach. 
Anyway, I tried it with one folder and searching in it led to a generic error message (An error occured, please try again). The event log doesn't show anything. Is there a log file for errors in OWA?

Comment: Try to rebuild the search index on the Exchange server, here is a similar thread for your reference: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1856962-exchange-2013-public-folders-search-issue